# How do I get rid of this white bar above my iPad keyboard?

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard

How do I remove this white strip on my iPad keyboard ?

Disabling shortcut and the predictive thing don't work.

[image]

Comment: I think it could be permanent for "languages" where prediction is supported by iOS.